# Emit local variable values during Groovy Shell execution

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Consider that we have the following Groovy script:

```
temp = a + b
temp * 10
```

Now, given that `a` and `b` are bound to the context with their respective values, and that the script is executed using a groovy shell script.

Is there a way I could obtain the value of the`temp` variable assignment, without printing/logging the value to the console? For instance, given `a=2` and `b=3`, I would like to not only know that the script returned `50` but also that `temp=5`. Is there a way to intercept every assignment to capture the values?

Any suggestions or alternatives are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture all bindings and assignments from the script by passing a [`Binding`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html) instance to the `GroovyShell` object. Consider following example:

```
def binding = new Binding()
def shell = new GroovyShell(binding)

def script = '''
a = 2
b = 3
temp = a + b
temp * 10
'''

println shell.run(script, 'script.groovy', [])

println binding.variables
```

Running this script prints following two lines to the console:

```
50
[args:[], a:2, b:3, temp:5]
```

If you want to access the value of `temp` script variable you simply do:

```
binding.variables.temp
```

Comment: You're the man! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.